# Laravel8 - Vue3 display images from storage

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I Know there is a way to link storage folder in public folder, But I need another way.

So this is my question: is there any other way that I can display my images from storage folder without link it?

This is folders structure:

`Storage->app->public->Categories->example.jpg`

I need to display the images from the Categories folder several times in Vue3 FrontEnd.

Comment: wdu mean by link it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Write a controller with image returning. Something like this (**it's not production ready code, just concept**).

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke($image_name)
    {
        $patch = 'Categories/'.$image_name.'.jpg';
        if(! Storage::exists($patch)){
             throw new HttpNotFoundException();
        }
        return response(Storage::get($patch))
            ->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    }
}

Route::get('images/{image_name}', ImageController::class);

<img src ="/images/example">
```

Comment: its works but I have problem with the route, if route like that: http://localhost:8000/categories/images/Categories/QXvxJoQHzC9KCgGJRy8jOIKPVyhABR0AKR9bqRxz.jpg it work but it like that:  http://localhost:8000/categories/27/images/Categories/QXvxJoQHzC9KCgGJRy8jOIKPVyhABR0AKR9bqRxz.jpg  it return  404

Comment: Pls read documentation. If you want to define route with category id - just define it. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters